# Angular2 need the result of a async get to allow access to a route

Tags: http, angular, angular-routing

I'm using a AuthGuard to protect my routes, making sure that a user is logged in correctly before he gets to see the dashboard of the app.

AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(
    next:  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    // return true;
    return this.userService.getValidLoginCheck();
}
```

However The getValidLoginCheck() does not return a boolean:

```
getValidLoginCheck(): boolean {
    let headers = new Headers();

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    headers.append('authorization', this.getToken());

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/checkToken', options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {return data.message === 'valid token' });

  }
```

I know why this is happening, but how can I make the getValid... function wait for the http.get to finish so I can guard my routes correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The CanActivate method accepts 3 types of responses (Observable, Promise and boolean), here is the signature of the method:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
```

Thus, you can take advantage of the Observable response and turn your Service's Observable into an Observable like this:

```
canActivate(
    next:  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {

       return new Observable<boolean>((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
         this.userService.getValidLoginCheck()
         .subscribe(data => {observer.next(data.message === 'valid token')},
          error => { console.log("error while calling getValidLoginCheck" ); observer.next(false)});
         observer.complete();
       });
}
```

You should be returning an observable from your service:

```
getValidLoginCheck(): Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers();

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    headers.append('authorization', this.getToken());

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/checkToken', options)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

This is what I did and it is working for me, I prefer to call a method inside the subscribe and send the observer and the http response and then evaluate the response inside the isolated method but that's my personal preference, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by return observable from can activate

```
allowed: Observable<boolean>
getValidLoginCheck(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    headers.append('authorization', this.getToken());
//save URL from routerStateSnapshot from canActivate like URL = state.url
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/auth/checkToken', options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data =>  { this.allowed = Observable.of(true);
```

this.router.navigateByUrl(URL);
    return data.message === 'valid token' }, err=> { this.allowed = Observable.of(true);})
    return this.allowed;

Comment: The app is being loaded but not the component because the observable is undefined at first. How can I let it wait untill it is not defined to return something?

Comment: What do mean by return something it should wait till canActivate return true. Do you want to show waiting state on UI ?

Comment: it doesn't show the component when it is turned to true

Comment: Save the result in some authService and return true from canActivate based on flag else execute current logic. On success form the request navigate to component again

Comment: not possible in my program architecture. Also this is a lot of hassle to just do something that should be very simple.

Comment: See my edits in above answer. You will get form canActivate param

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at. If you mean that I should access the router in a service, that seems like bad practice.